# C# Web API DTO combining two Objects in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Hi I'm a newbie to C# and DTO's and I'm looking for a bit of advice in writing a method.  Basically I have two transfer objects, Members and Source.  What I'm trying to achieve is display a list of Members from a specific Source.

The only problem is I need to be able to display Members associated with a SourceId from a SourceRef. As I dont want to pass the sensitive MemberID and SourceId so each has a reference id and thats how I will be identifying them in my API

Member Object

```
public class MemberObj
{
    public int memId { get; set; }
    public String memRef { get; set; }
    public String fName { get; set; }
    public String lName { get; set; }
    public String email { get; set; }
    public String detail { get; set; }
    public int sourceId { get; set; }
}
```

Source Object

```
public class SourceObj
{
    public int sourceId { get; set; }
    public String sourceRef { get; set; }
}
```

So I would like to go to the address for example

```
http://..../api/Member/Source/{sourceRef}
```

and display the list of Members associated to the sourceId via the sourceRef

I came up with something along these lines....

```
public IEnumerable<MemberObj> GetMem(String code)
    {
        var sc = db.Sources;
        var thisSrc = sc.Where(s => s.sourceRef == code).SingleOrDefault();


        return db.Members.Select(s => new MemberObj
        {
            memId = s.memId,
            firstName = s.firstName,
            lastName = s.lastName,
            email = s.emailAddress,
            memRef = s.memRef

          }).AsEnumerable().Where(s => s.sourceRef== thisSrc.sourceRef);
```

But this returns nothing.

Comment: please give us more what you want

Comment: The problem im having is that i cannot seem to be able to write a working method that will return Members based on a sourceRef

Comment: What doesn't work? Have you any specific error?

Comment: Its more of a logic/syntax error, im not sure how to get the two objects to work together. As my Member DTO doesnt contain sourceRef, but i want to be able to display members by sourceRef

Comment: Should your where clause not include `.Where(b => b.sourceId == thisSrc.sourceId)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following accepts `code` as the sourceRef and returns the `SourceID` that the ref corresponds too.

From here, it simply filters all members to only the ones with the matching `sourceID`. (I don't have a copy of VS near me so the syntax may be out! If only Notepad++ had intelisense...)

```
public IEnumerable<MemberObj> GetMem(String code)
{
    int soureID = db.Sources.Where(s => s.sourceRef == code).SingleOrDefault().sourceID; //I'm assuming code is the source ref??

    //Insert and handle your sourceID == 0 checks here.
    //...

    return db.Members.Where(m => m.sourceId == sourceID);
}
```

Comment: Would this throw a problem as code and sourceRef is a String and the new sourceID variable will be an int.  Would this cause a confilict?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, I don't believe it would, as your comparing the strings seperatly to the ID, so they should never conflict.

Comment: Wouldnt this  `db.Sources.Where(s => s.sourceRef == code)`  return for example RFC12 but storing it into an int??

Comment: Ah yes i see, i didnt even know what was possible to filter it to a specific type like .sourceID  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
public IEnumerable<MemberObj> GetMem(String code)
{
    var thisSrc = db.Sources
                    .Where(s => s.sourceRef == code)
                    .SingleOrDefault();

    if(thisSrc == null)
       return Enumerable.Empty<MemberObj>();

    return db.Members.Where(m => m.sourceId == thisSrc.sourceId);
}
```

Take in account, that you should handle the case when there are more than one source by given `code` (`SingleOrDefault` throws an exception in that case.)
If you are sure that is not a case use `FirstOrDefault` instead.

Comment: Would this not return a database object and not my DTO?? Just my db.Members has a load of fields and my DTO filters out to only 5 fields.

Comment: @Freeman For that, create instances of anonymous type then map them to your DTO.

Answer (score 0):

Just building into Hamlet's answer, you could do something like this to return a DTO instead of your Member Entity:

```
public IEnumerable<MemberDTO> GetMem(String code)
{
    //Get the source object by sourceRef
    var thisSrc = db.Sources
                    .Where(s => s.sourceRef == code)
                    .SingleOrDefault();

    if(thisSrc == null)
       return Enumerable.Empty<MemberObj>();

   //Filter Members by sourceId and map the results to a MemberDTO with less fields
   var data = (from m in db.Members
               where m.sourceId == thisSrc.sourceId
               select new MemberDTO
               {
                   MemberId = m.memId,
                   //map the rest of your DTO fields..

               }).ToList();

    return data;
}
```